# Problem with stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have add stylesheet link tag to my application. I'm sure its worked. because in another place is working. but if I run at my computer it did not working. I mean my application cant load css

when I seen at view source the result is :

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000//javascripts/application.js?1258048544" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="http://localhost:3000//stylesheets/jquery.autocomplete.css?1258048544" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I'm sure it shouldnt appear double slash // after domain or localhost:3000. weird why in other computer it was worked.

Have you any suggestion for this case? how to change double slash with single?

btw I use ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some details about how you call the stylesheet_link_tag helper method.

Comment: If you visit one of those addresses in a browser, do you see your CSS?

Comment: yes i do, but i still confused why in another computer with // it worked. Oya please give me some detail stylesheet_link_tag call helper method

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I'm experiencing the exact same problem on a Rails 2.3.5 app. My stylesheet and js includes in my layouts are exhibiting the same behavior described above. Plus, when I hit the app from my machine's IP, it still uses localhost for these links. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Rails helpers should not render an absolute url, it should simply be a relative path.

```
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.autocomplete.css?1250281505" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Make sure you are using the `stylesheet_link_tag` properly - do not use a leading slash or the trailing `.css` when specifying the stylesheet name. Same for `javascript_include_tag`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.autocomplete" %>
```

Comment: Look this is my code <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'jquery/jquery.facebox',

                                        'jquery/jquery.bgiframe',

                                        'jquery/jquery.autocomplete',

                                        'fckeditor/fckeditor' %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery.autocomplete'%>



  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main', 'facebox' %>

Comment: Maybe you have `ActionController::Base.asset_host = 'localhost:3000/'` set in your environment?

Comment: No I just set my environtment default

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

> Relative paths from root-stucture: "/your/path/to/file.ext"
>
> Relative paths from the current file "your/path/to/file.ext"

Answer (score 0):

Try these helper methods:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_merged 'jquery.autocomplete.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js'%>
```

*Works with http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and just discovered the issue–it may or may not work for you.

My app uses the Facebooker gem to integrate with Facebook Connect. In my facebooker.yml file, if I had a trailing slash in my callback_url setting, I would get the same behavior as you described. Removing the trailing slash fixed the issue.